# Android Studio unable to save settings - Failed to save settings

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm struggling with Android Studio Electric Reel on Windows 10 stopping to work as expected.
[image]

AS gives me error "Unable to save settings. Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio" after attempting to run an app to my device.
After which I'm not only unable to run/stop/restart or debug the app on any device, I'm also unable to open settings via File>Settings.

The behaviour includes:

- inability to open any sort of setting through AS menu
- Restart the app after first run (the first time it only builds, doesn't install and gets stuck on the screen above where I don't even have the option to build anymore)
- adb.exe and OpenJDK running in the background even when AS is not running

What I've tried so far:

1. Restarting AS and clearing its cache.
2. Removing AS including caches in AppData, the Android project I'm developing, Roaming, .android, .m2, .gradle, SDK.
3. Reinstalling SDK
4. Using custom, Embedded JDK or jbr-11
5. Reinstalling computer combined with any of the steps
6. Using a new laptop - I've tried running the same project on a new laptop and the issue reappeared.
7. Exempting adb.exe and all the files stated in step 1. from Windows Defender (I don't use any antivirus) and turning off Ransomware protection (controlled access to files)
8. Upgrade/downgrade libraries and Gradle

So far it looks like some internal problem in Android Studio. I have an administrator account on this laptop, so it is possible Android Studio is trying to save some cache elsewhere, which it doesn't have access to. Although I haven't found any signs of this (when I ran AS as an administrator or in logs).

Occasionally after reinstalling everything, it does start to work, but it keeps on resurfacing, so I turned to issuetracker, which takes Google to resolve for ever, as usual.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271896089

It is also possible, that the problem occurs with very specific changes in the code (no clue how that could have any impact), but there is a certain pattern of me using the branch it started not working on/merging it to new one or changing the code manually in a new branch.

Comment: Can you open settings when in an empty project?

Comment: @zomega yes. It starts only after successful build and "failed install" (doesn't actually give any error). So I can change anything I want right until that point - then it starts giving the "Unable to save settings" error as well.

Comment: @zomega just tried creating completely new blank project and it works on its own, but if the problem starts occuring in my project the new project doesn't work either.

Comment: I'd try to delete the .idea folder from your project which causes the errors. It contains project specific settings. Perhaps this causes the errors.

Comment: @zomega That's one of the things I've tried. I've tried to delete all caches known to me, which I listed above.

Comment: Create an empty project and copy file by file from your existing project into it until it fails to launch.